# Wishing "God speed"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Do we say, "**god speed**" when we wish somebody a good ride?

What other wishes are there of the kind?

Comment: A good ride on what?

Comment: I think on whatever is rideable.

Comment: Literally anything? Rollercoaster? Tractor? Camel? If that's what you mean, fine, just making sure :)

Comment: @cjl750 I guess, am I being asked back my question?

Comment: It just struck me as a broad category at first, so wanted to see if you were looking for something to suit a particular circumstance. No worries.

Comment: Not in PDE, except at Renaissance Faires and in space travel. Everything in between, not used.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I've definitely used the word "godspeed" with friends, but mostly as a joke. I have never been to a Renaissance Faire, but I do like Game of Thrones. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In the traditional, literal sense, you would say ***Godspeed!*** to people who are going on a journey. You are wishing them fast and safe travels.

***Godspeed!*** is sometimes said ironically or sarcastically to friends who part ways for smaller reasons. For example, if someone were to go on a dangerous rollercoaster ride, then yes, you could joke and say, ***Godspeed!***

It's a funny joke, because it's such an old, serious word, yet you are using it in a lighthearted way.

Other similar terms:

> God be with ye!
>
> May the road rise to meet you!
>
> Safe travels!